# Laptop internal screen not working after Kernel update (Intel XE)

Tags: 20.04, kernel, display, intel-graphics

I have a problem with the latest Kernel versions (currently 5.11.0.25) on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

The system has updated the Kernel to 5.11.0.25 and the internal screen in the laptop is not working (black / blank screen is already during boot). However, the HDMI output works, although it does not use it - when I connected the laptop via HDMI to an external monitor, it displays a purple / blank screen, and then (blindly enter the password and click enter) login is performed and the desktop is displayed - but appears as if it were a secondary screen.

When I click the right mouse button and choose the duplicate screen option, the desktop is displayed only on the external monitor - nothing is displayed on the internal monitor, even though the system can see it.

What should I do? I have an HP Pavilion 15 laptop with an i5-1135G7 processor and Intel XE graphics card. The laptop's internal screen only works on Kernel 5.8.0.43 ... Why doesn't it work with newer Kernel versions?

The laptop has the latest HP firmware.